# Error when try move element of array to eax NASM

Tags: nasm, x86-64, mach-o

I write assembly code

```
 section .data
     mas dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

 section .text
 global start

 start:
     xor eax, eax
     xor si, si
     xor ecx, 20
 sum:
      push mas[si]
      add ax, mas[si]
      add esi, 4
      cmp ecx, esi
 jne sum
```

But when i compile i got error

```
test.asm:12: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
test.asm:13: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

What's a problem? NASM v 2.13

Comment: Change `mas[si]` to `[mas+si]`

Comment: @MichaelPetch now i got 

     `test.asm:12: error: impossible combination of address sizes`
     `test.asm:13: error: impossible combination of address sizes`
     `test.asm:13: error: invalid effective address`

Comment: Are you creating 16-bit program or 32-bit. You seem to have a mixture. If you are generating 32-bit code then make sure addresses use 32-bit registers. Instead of SI you should use ESI.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I build like `nasm -f macho64 test.asm`, how i understood, i create 64-bit program.

Comment: I'm guessing you are probably assembling as 64-bit code in this case yet it is a mixture of 16 and 32-bit

Comment: @MichaelPetch If i try build with `macho32` i got error: `test.asm:13: error: invalid effective address`